# Recapturing unused OPT time for use after another program

Tags: usa

I did my Masters in Journalism and got OPT approved for one year. But did not work and left the country. Surrendered the opt after 8 weeks. I plan to do a STEM Masters. Will the 9.5 months of unused OPT be considered after the second masters?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate. The question here is whether the student can recapture their unused OPT time that was previously authorized but then relinquished. The other question doesn't involve any unused time. Based on this FAQ's question about recapturing time I think the answer is still "no", however: https://www.ice.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Document/2016/i765optStemFaq.pdf

Comment: @krubo Thanks for your comment. I voted to reopen. I also agree with your observation that the answer to this question is likely "no."